# Getting a wrong value of $\pi$

Tags: geometry, approximation, arc-length, experimental-mathematics

**I read this question somewhere**

Let a square of length 1 unit and a circle is inscribed in it such that it touches the sides of square.

Now cut small portion(outside the circle) of square from each corner. [image]

As you can se **the perimeter of square is still 4** after removing this portion.

Continue this process i.e. cut the square in such a way that shape of cutting square tends to the shape of circle.

**Now the main thing is**

Perimeter of square =$4$

Perimeter of circle= $2\pi \frac{1}{2}$=$\pi$

Since the the shape of square tends to the shape of circle

Therefore perimter of square $=$ Perimeter of circle ( or may be approximately equal to circle)

That is $\pi =4\ or\  approx \ 4$

If we take side of square of length $a,a>0$ we also reached to the same result.

Can anyone explain whats wrong in this. I am unable to figure out.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you were calculating the value of cake.

Comment: @Batominovski can you please explain it further .  Whats wrong with  this process

Comment: This is one of the most [upvoted questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4) on this site...

Comment: Shape $A$ tends to shape $B$ does not entail that the length of the boundary of shape $A$ tends to the length of the boundary of shape $B$.

Comment: [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) $\ne$ [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)

Comment: Thanks for direction